# Callback when internet connection changed

Tags: java, internet-connection

I have a java code that downloads a picture from web to my hard disk. I want to run it at startup and when internet is connected it downloads the picture, otherwise waits until internet connects. A way is to check internet connection every moments but i search for a better way?
I want it supports windows OS.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String imageUrl = "http://imgs.yooz.ir/yooz/walls/yooz-950616.jpg";
        //the imageUrl changes every few days.

        String destinationFile = "C:\\Wallpaper.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        try {
            InputStream is=url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code which does the download?

Comment: do you want support for all OS?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/. You can trigger your program on connecting to internet

Comment: I add my code that does the download @sinclair.

Comment: I want it supports windows OS @sidgate.

Comment: Thank you @sidgate. I look the groovypost url, but i want do it by a java code!

Comment: @mhm you can trigger your java code from the the event mentioned in the link

Comment: @sidgate i want to publish my code and want everyone install it, it automatically do it's work.